# Calculating how much of polygon is within certain boundary in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-3, area, overlapping-features

I work for a local authority and I'm measuring the surface area of river catchments inside our local authority.

I have a polygon layer showing me the catchments but a few of them go over our boundary into other local authorities - so just measuring the polygon's surface area would be no good.

Is there any way I can measure how much of the polygons 'sit' inside our boundary (which I also have as a separate layer)? I'm using QGIS 3.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Overlap analysis](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#overlap-analysis) tool:

> This algorithm calculates the area and percentage cover by which
> features from an input layer are overlapped by features from a
> selection of overlay layers. New attributes are added to the output
> layer reporting the total area of overlap and percentage of the input
> feature overlapped by each of the selected overlay layers.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. The only porblem I'm getting is I don't know what unit the area is calculated in and I can't seem to find a way to set it to kilometres squared.

Comment: It is in the unit of your coordinate system. If it is meters, use Field Calculator to alter it, or to add and calculate a new field. If it is in degrees it gets a little bit more complicated, but you can still use field calculator.

Answer (score 1):

You can clip the river layer with the boundary layer. Create a field like `area_sqkm` and get the area via `round(($area/1000000),2)`.

Then join that layer's field to the *unclipped* river layer and rename the field appropriately.